# how to insert the contents of an `\input`ed file into the source?

Tags: input, external-files

Is there a utility that will take a LaTeX source file, find all the `\input{some_external_file}` lines, and insert the contents of those external files into the master document without compiling to PDF?  I could write my own script to do this but it seems like a common enough need that someone would have solved it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It's called [latexpand](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexpand) and does what you are describing.